# how to change chrome default copy number

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, browser

I have web app that generates receipts and uses JavaScript to call the print dialog when printing out the receipts. Is there a way to set the default number of copies in the print dialog from one to two? I'm using the Chrome browser and the default setting is to print only one copy.

Comment: can you just call print() twice?

Comment: this will not make it

Comment: You cannot set count of copies via javascript. Printing is part of operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set count of copies via javascript. Printing is part of operating system.

Comment: so what should i do to change chrome setting ?

Comment: There is no chrome setting for printing. As I said in the answer, Print window is part of operating system. Not chrome's. Chrome just starts it. You cannot set number of copies from chrome.

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: You have to develop a local software with C#, C++ etc. You cannot manage operating system's components via javascript or browser.